# How to use Windows shared folder to be a vagrant synced_folder?

Tags: windows, vagrant, vagrantfile, smb

There are 3 machines:

#### 1."desktop"

Windows 10 desktop
(Has the windows shared folder in its hard disk).
NOTE: This is my colleague's machine.

#### 2."laptop"

Windows 10 laptop
(In the same local area network of "desktop", and can read and write the shared folder).
NOTE: This is my machine.

#### 3."vagrant-centos7"

vagrant virtual machine centos7
(a guest machine hosted at "laptop" use vagrant virtualbox provider).

#### Now my question is like this:

I use "laptop", need make a "desktop" windows shared folder to be a synced folder to "vagrant-centos7".

I tried this vagrantfile setting, but faild.
"z://" is  windows map network drive of the "desktop" share folder.
192.168.0.108 is the ip of "desktop"

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "Z://", "/vagrant_data2", 
                            type: "smb",
                            smb_host: "192.168.0.108",
                            smb_username: "abc",
                            smb_password: "123456"
```

The error message is:

Host path: Z:

Stderr: dev or path not exists.

thanks for any helps :)

Comment: please specify which version of vagrant do you use. older version had a bug which was fixed.

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to use a root folder like that. I fixed sharing a parent folder and then using like `Z:/MyFolder`. But it made my web project very very slow, like 8~10 sec each request, against 2~3 on a normal folder.